# Изменить внешний вид textarea в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, input, textarea

Подскажите, как менять textarea для того, чтоб он имел следующий вид как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гуглил, не смог найти. Возможно плохо конечно гуглил, но все же...

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Дополните вопрос. Верхнее поле для того чтобы туда вводили текст, его можно легко сделать как инпутом, так и textarea. Для чего тогда нижнее поле? .Если там должен появляться текст то какая механика? Он просто переносится туда, или копируется из верхнего или вообще как-то по-другому?

Comment: @kizoso так нарисовано в макете )

Comment: а как нужно сделать то? или как вы предполагаете должно быть?

Answer (score 1):

в таблицу вставь и стилизуй. задай таблице задний фон, у textarea убери border, задний фон прозрачный, запрети менять размер. или тоже самое в диве с label

P.S.Никогда не задумывался, но мне понравилось. Завтра вечером сделаю.